# VBA Filesystemobject copy data from subfolders

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

I'm having trouble getting my code to work properly, it runs however nothing is copied into the destination file.

I don't really understand why it is not copying from the files or what I need to add for it to work. What I am trying to do is open a large amount of files in subfolders of a directory that I need to copy information from certain cells e.g. C5, D51 etc into A2, B2 of the destination file.

```
Sub Copdata()
Call GetFiles("D:\data\Analysis\records\")
End Sub

Sub GetFiles(ByVal path As String)
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim folder As Object
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(path)

Dim subfolder As Object
Dim file As Object

For Each subfolder In folder.SubFolders
    GetFiles (subfolder.path)
Next subfolder

Set destSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
r = 0
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each file In folder.Files
    Set fromWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(file)
    With fromWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard")
    r = r + 1
        destSheet.Range("A2").Offset(r).Value = .Range("C5").Value
        destSheet.Range("B2").Offset(r).Value = .Range("D51").Value
    End With
    fromWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
Next file

Set fso = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set subfolder = Nothing
Set file = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Where did you declare and give a value to `r` variable? If it is zero, everything of all open workbooks is returned in "A2", respectively, "B2"... At least, incrementing it in the loop, if no `Option Explicit` on top of the module where the code exists. I mean, try using `r = r + 1` after `With fromWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard")`.

Comment: Thank you have updated it, however still does not seem to return any data.

Comment: Strange... Please, firstly comment the line `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`. You do not need optimization right now... Then,  place a break point on `Set fromWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(file)` and after stopping on it run the code step by step, pressing `F8` and see what's happening. Is the workbook open? Does  `.Range("C5")` contain any value, if so does it firstly write it in "A2" of the active sheet and so on... If there are values in the ranges where to copy from, theoretically it should work. If not, do you have TeamViewer of AnyDesk installed?

Comment: Have made a few updates and it does now copy, with one issue that it does not continually copy the data down always using the the next row it appears to restart for every set of files in a folder.

Comment: What do you mean by "few updates"? We can try helping if you see what you use... Please, try declaring `r` on top of the module (in the declarations area) as  `Private r As Long`. Then, initialize it as zero before calling the Sub: `r = 0`, `GetFiles "D:\data\Analysis\records\"`. If you want to add values after a specific row, you should use `r = x`, where `x` is the row number starting from, to add records...

Comment: I get a compile error, when it goes into a new subfolder it pastes over the data from the previous is there a way to make r always be an empty row at the bottom of the data in the destination sheet?

Comment: It shouldn't... Now `r` is continuously incremented keeping its previous value. Except the case you forgot to make it `0` after running once... You can calculate the first empty row. `Dim lR as Long` `lR = destSheet.Range("A" & destSheet.Rows.count).End(xlup).row + 1`. Then use `destSheet.Range("A" & lR).Value = .Range("C5").Value`

Comment: is it possible to provide me with what the code should look like? using private r as long as it errors for me I might be doing it wrong

Comment: I was trying to make you understand why **your** code does not work and what is to be done to correct it. But i can place a simpler code, firstly placing in an array all necessary files/workbooks. Since, you open them in Excel, they should be Excel files... Then, iterating between the array elements and do what you try doing. Calculating the last empty row, will also allow iterating between workbooks in other locations and start adding them on the first empty row.

Answer (score 0):

Please, use the next function. It will return (in an array) all workbooks from a specific locations (including all subfolders):

```
Private Function getAllFiles(strFold As String, Optional strExt As String = "*.*") As Variant
    getAllFiles = filter(Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").Exec("cmd /c dir """ & strFold & strExt & """ /b/s").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), "\")
End Function
```

It can be called in your existing code in the next way:

```
Sub Copdata()
    GetFiles "D:\data\Analysis\records\"
End Sub

Sub GetFiles(ByVal path As String)
   Dim arrFiles, destSheet As Worksheet, lastR As Long, fromWorkbook As Workbook, i As Long
   
   Set destSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
   lastR = destSheet.Range("A" & destSheet.rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1 'last empty row on A:A col
   
   arrFiles = getAllFiles(path, "*.xls*") 'place all necessary workbook in an array
   
   For i = 0 To UBound(arrFiles)           'iterate between the array elements (workbooks full name)
        Set fromWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(arrFiles(i))
        With fromWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard")
            destSheet.Range("A" & lastR + i).value = .Range("C5").value
            destSheet.Range("B" & lastR + i).value = .Range("D51").value
        End With
        fromWorkbook.Close False
   Next i
End Sub
```

Not tested, but it should work. Except some (possible) typos. In such a case please, explain what error on which code line...

Please, test it and send some feedback.

It assumes that A:A and B:B have the same number of records... That's why it calculates the last empty row on A:A and use it on B:B, too...

Comment: I do not understand this level of vba but it gives a run-time error '-2147024891 (80070005) Access is denied

Comment: @Orfevre I said "what error on **which code line"**...

Comment: this is the code line - getAllFiles = Filter(Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").Exec("cmd /c dir """ & strFold & strExt & """ /b/s").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), "\")

Comment: @Orfevre Do you use MacOS? Is the main folder path ending in backslash ("\")?

Comment: use windows and yes path is ending in \

Comment: @Orfevre Then, I cannot imagine what that error should mean in this context. It works without problem on my computer and is faster than the standard iteration between subfolders way. I cannot reproduce the error and I do not have time now to investigate the issue. I will try that when I will have some available time...